# how can I prevent preventDefault from removing the submit button from $_POST?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form with two submit buttons:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

I need to manipulate some things on the form before it is submitted so I used this jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.originalEvent && e.preventDefault();
    //manipulate stuff
    this.submit();
});
```

The problem is, I need to know which button was clicked at the back end but

`$_POST['Submit']` and `$_POST['Delete']`

are both `undefined`. It seems the inputs are removed from the post array by the jQuery.

What would be a good way to solve that issue?

Comment: Can you capture which one client-side (with jQuery) and update a hidden form field?

Comment: @BobBrown I'm thinking that's what I'm going to have to do

Comment: Buttons are removed, because you manually submit the form (it is not submitted by the user anymore actually). I recommend Rejanu's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about it with two event handlers for each button and a hidden input to tell the php which action is requested. As an addition I would advice you to checkout Ajax.
Code is as follows:

```
$('#update').click(function (e) {
    e.originalEvent && e.preventDefault();
    //manipulate stuff
    $("form").append("<input type = 'hidden' name = 'action' value = 'update' />");
    this.submit();
});
$('#delete').click(function (e) {
    e.originalEvent && e.preventDefault();
    //manipulate stuff
    $("form").append("<input type = 'hidden' name = 'action' value = 'delete' />");
    this.submit();
});
```

And on the back-end side you'll get what was submitted in `$_POST['action']` that is either going to be "update" or "delete"

Comment: Great, I was able to extract the original button with `$(e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget)` and create a hidden input based on that

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you add an action as input type hidden and two buttons that may or may not be a part of the form. Add event listeners to the buttons to know when those are clicked and change input action field accordignly, then submit the form.

First, give your form a name or id, rather id.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value=""/>

<input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete"/>

$('input[type="submit"][name="Update"]').click(function() {
   $('input[type="hidden"][name="action"]').val('Update');
   $("#something").submit();
});
$('input[type="submit"][name="Submit"]').click(function() {
   $('input[type="hidden"][name="action"]').val('Delete');
   $("#something").submit();
});
```